# A problem with openning the file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Hi
I want to open the file that is in a place in my computer . I use this code but it doesn't open it . How can I open that file ?

```
QString path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\vnb.txt" ;
QFile inFile( path );
if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
return -1 ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Never use `\` as the file separator in QT. Always use `/` and QT will make sure that it is always portable. This is clearly stated in the documentation of [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html#details).

Comment: ...or escape the \ (C:\\Program Files instead of C:\Program Files)

Comment: But this is not about portability. Where is it mentioned in the docs that the function will fail if u use \ slashes on windows?

Comment: "QFile expects the file separator to be '/' regardless of operating system. The use of other separators (e.g., '\') is not supported.". It might work, but it's not recommended. The choice is yours.

Comment: The problem here is that the compiler will treat the backslashed letters as escape codes.

Comment: **QDir::seperator();** is directory separator which cross-platform